# Enable dropdown menu on checking a check box

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a drop down box in the `<table>`:

```
<TR > 
    <TD colspan="2" class="text1">
        <div align="right">
            <FONT color="#000000"> 
                <INPUT name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="services[]" value="Employee ">
            </FONT>
        </div>
    </TD>

    <TD width="321" align="center" valign="top" class="text1">
        <DIV align="left">Employee</DIV>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

When a user selects the above check box I want the following drop down menu to be enabled:

```
<TR> 
    <TD width="155" height="25" align="right" class="text1">
        <div align="right">Enquiry Type/For</div>
    </TD>

    <TD align="left" colspan="2" height="25">&nbsp;
        <select name = "type" id = "type">
            <!--<option value = "general">General</option>-->
            <option value = "general">General</option>
            <option value = "employee">employee</option>
            <option value = "student">student</option>
        </select>
    </TD>
</TR>
```

How do I do that?

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Patax/1/)

Comment: You can call an ajax page using jquery on the onchange of the first dropdown box.

Answer (score 2):

First, change your checkbox id to `services` :

```
<INPUT name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="services" value="Employee " rel="services">
```

Then Change your drop down:

```
<select name = "type" id = "type" disabled="disabled">
```

Now, use jQuery:

```
$(function(){
 $("[rel=services]").click(function(){
  $("#type").attr("disabled", false);
 });
});
```

Note: `type` is a reversed keyword, so please change the `name` of drop down to something else.

Comment: I have to keep services[] since there are many checkbox values and id for each of the textboxes is given as array "services[]" so how can I modify javascript you gave to suit my code needs?

Comment: What I mean is - yes there are many checkoxes but I want the dropdown to be enabled only when this particular checkbox is checked

Answer (score 1):

you can change your script according to the code below.....

```
function check() {

if (($("#check:checked").length) > 0) {
    $("#type").removeAttr("disabled");
} else {
    $("#type").attr("disabled", "disabled");

}
}
```

for demo:[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cB9FC/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i think you like this

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function()
{
    if($(this).prop('checked'))
    $('#type').show();
    else
        $('#type').hide();
});
```

Fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/Patax/2/)

Comment: This is nice but I have many checkboxes . tha is why I have given id as "services[]" for each of the textbox. How do I use your code to suit my coding needs? The solution that you gave is nice but I would like to know how to modify it for my code

Comment: If there are multiple checkboxes, for every checkbox, it will call the function.

Comment: @ProgrammingStudent:
What I mean is - yes there are many checkoxes but I want the dropdown to be enabled only when this particular checkbox is checked

Comment: wait i suggest you how we enable dropdown for only one checkbox?

Comment: @user2822187: first you remove bracket from your checkbox id, it use only for regex.

Comment: See in jsfiddle it was working, what problem occuring.. can you use jquerry version file also..

Comment: yeah jsfiddle i tried.. i dont know what is wrong in my file. I am using your same code..btw I have many of the foll <td>
<TR > 
              <TD height="18" colspan="2" class="text1"><div align="right"><FONT color="#000000"> 
                  <INPUT name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="services[]" value="Protection and Indemnity Services">
                  </FONT></div></TD>
              <TD width="321" height="18" align="center" valign="top" class="text1"><DIV align="left"> 
                  Protection and Indemnity Services </DIV></TD>
            </TR>

Comment: @Subhash: I tried the fiddle in my file it is not giving the desired result

Answer (score 0):

No Jquery solution:

```
document.getElementById('services').onchange = function () {
  document.getElementById('type').disabled = !document.getElementById('type').disabled;
};
```

notice I changed the checkbox id to 'services', and added disabled to the select:

```
<select name = "type" id = "type" disabled>
```

Comment: I have many checkboxes with id=services[]. Only when one particular checkbox is checked,only then the dropdown should be enabled

Comment: you shouldn't have the same id for more then 1 element on page.

Comment: yes i know but suppose if i use services[] does it work like array? 
I am actually modifying a code written by previous person . I only have to modify it to enable dropdown

Comment: you mean like <input id='services[1]'>, <input id='services[2]'>?
you do understand its not an array but a string?

if so: just use some other string such as id='services-1', id='services-2'.
(the brackets are no good there).

Answer (score 0):

Here is your solution

page1.php

```
<table id='mytable'>
<TR > 
    <TD colspan="2" class="text1">
        <div align="right">
            <FONT color="#000000"> 
                <INPUT name="services[]" type="checkbox" id="services[]" value="Employee ">
            </FONT>
        </div>
    </TD>

    <TD width="321" align="center" valign="top" class="text1">
        <DIV align="left">Employee</DIV>
    </TD>
</TR>
</table>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $('input[name="services[]"]').change(function(){
        if(!$(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(".newRow").remove();
        } else {
            $.ajax({
                url:"page2.php",
                success: function(response) {
                    $("#mytable").append(response);
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

page2.php

```
<TR class="newRow"> 
    <TD width="155" height="25" align="right" class="text1">
        <div align="right">Enquiry Type/For</div>
    </TD>

    <TD align="left" colspan="2" height="25">&nbsp;
        <select name = "type" id = "type">
            <!--<option value = "general">General</option>-->
            <option value = "general">General</option>
            <option value = "employee">employee</option>
            <option value = "student">student</option>
        </select>
    </TD>
</TR>
```